# Unable to setup hazelcast cluster in multiple server using multicast

Tags: hazelcast

Here i am trying to setup hazelcast cluster in multiple server using multicast ,But its not communicating to each other ,Its running as standalone
My configuration is

```html
<join> <multicast enabled="true"> 
<multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group> 
<multicast-port>54327</multicast-port> 
<multicast-time-to-live>32</multicast-time-to-live> 
<multicast-timeout-seconds>2</multicast-timeout-seconds> 
<trusted-interfaces> <interface>192.168.1.*</interface> </trustedinterfaces> 
</multicast> 
<tcp-ip enabled="false"> </tcp-ip> 
<aws enabled="false"> </aws> 
</join>
```

Same like http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Setting_Up_Clusters/Discovering_Members_by_Multicast.html
Iam using the same configuration in all the 3 different machines (example: 192.168.1.24,192.168.1.25,192.168.1.26
Can anybody please help me !

Comment: Are you able to ping all machines from all machines? Secondly, how are you ensuring that multicast is enabled on your network?

Comment: yes i am able to ping..But how to check multicast enabled or not in my network?

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search on “How can I know if multicast is enabled” should give you numerous options.